# Best practice for communicating with a NodeJS server hosted locally from a Bluehost NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, server

I have a web application running on a Bluehost server. I am trying to retrieve files hosted on a local server. On the local server, I have port forwarding and NodeJS listening on port 3000. I could do 80 as well, but from what I have read, that is not safe.

The issue I am running into is mainly the SSL cert for the local Node instance. The web application requires post requests to be made to https:// sources.

What are some best practice approaches to making this work? I have heard about installing Apache and running a ProxyPass to port 3000, but I am still concerned that the port 80 will have no SSL. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First its worth noting that there are many approaches to hosting a web service.

Node can handle https connection, you should read the native https module documentation for how this works.

I tend to use Nginx (although apache is great and is a battle-tested solution) as a proxy server to node as, in general, I find it speeds up the process to get a product live. It also allows you to extract potential requirements from your node server, such as caching and SSL, so your node app can just focus on business requirements.

If you go for a proxy server, Nginx (and others), have modules that will handle SSL certificates. Lots of documentation online about how to set this up.

Something to keep in mind is that PORT 80 and 3000 are connection points for traffic. You will only be able to interact with the server on these ports if you bind and expose an application to them. If nothing is exposed to PORT 80, then connect attempts will just fail.

The best practices I tend to employ are:

1. No excuse not to use SSL nowadays, the standard is to expose https server on port 443.
2. If you choose to expose port 80, redirect all traffic to 443. This guarantees a secure connection.